# problems converting string to float python

Tags: python, string

```
def syntax_hilight_(event):
    for kw in keyword.kwlist:
        size = IntVar()
        begin = self.txt_field.search(kw, "1.0", stopindex = "end", count = size)
        #end_index = "%s + %sc" % (begin, size.get())
        print(size.get())
        size_int = float(size.get())
        while size_int > 1:
            size_int /= 10
        float(begin)
        end_index = float(begin) + size_int
        self.txt_field.tag_add("search", float(begin), float(end_index))
        self.txt_field.tag_config("search", foreground = "green")
```

When I run this function(press a key) I get this error:

```
File "C:/Users/roman_000/PycharmProjects/neuron/ide_custom.py", line 36, 
    in syntax_hilight_
float(begin)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

`begin` is a string which contains an index like 6.0, 5.9, 14.19 etc. I thought there are no problems with converting such strings to float

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Can you give some sample input-output examples? Also, your indentation is not correct.

Comment: You create an IntVar in your function, and then immediately call ``.get()`` on it.  This has no possibility of doing anything useful, as the var will never have a chance to be assigned a value.

Comment: my actual problem is I am stuck with converting string begin to float

Comment: just add print(begin) and have a look at it.

Comment: What *is* string `begin`? Give an actual example of a string that you want to convert to a float.

Comment: begin = "1.0" for example

Comment: `float("1.0") = 1.0` -- begin must not be what you think it is.

Comment: I mean when I run print(begin) is displays smth like 1.0, but it cannot be converted

Comment: Is `1.0` an actual example? (your wording "something like" makes me wonder). `float('1.0')` is non-problematic. Something else is going on.

Comment: Also -- having `float(begin)` on a line by itself is somewhat pointless. That statement (if successful) returns a float but doesn't modify the string. Since you are not assigning the value of `float(begin)` to a variable, the result of that line (if successful) is discarded, causing the line to have no effect (beyond crashing your program for some values of `begin`).

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs when `kw` cannot be found in the text and so `begin` will be empty which causes the `ValueError`.  Try do the highlight when `begin` is not empty.  Below is my suggested solution:

```
def syntax_hilight_(self):
    size = tk.IntVar()
    for kw in keyword.kwlist:
        begin = self.txt_field.search(kw, '1.0', stopindex='end', count=size)
        if begin:
            end_index = '%s + %sc' % (begin, size.get())
            self.txt_field.tag_add('search', begin, end_index)
            self.txt_field.tag_config('search', foreground='green')
```

Comment: This is a bug in python's ValueError  message, it should include the repr of the failing string.

Comment: This seems like it is probably the solution, although OP *explicitly* said that when they put in `print(begin)` they saw "smth [sic] like 1.0" -- which isn't what you see with `print('')`

Comment: @Gribouillis I wouldn't call it a bug -- although I agree that the error message in your approach is a little more helpful than the default error message in the special case of an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
try: float(begin)
except ValueError: raise RuntimeError(('could not convert to float', begin))
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but is a nice way to get an error message which might make debugging easier.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, only after checking with python, the original ValueError's message already contains the failing string, so I don't understand the OP's question. Why doesn't he post the string begin ?

Comment: I agree, it is strange. Still -- it is a nice idea (that not everybody knows about) to be able to catch runtime errors and make them more informative and then raise them again, although in this case the original error message should have been informative enough.

Comment: I contest the downvote I got on this. The RuntimeError above actually detects the empty string case that the ValueError failed to show.